# How do I write GCD asyncAfter in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, swift4

In earlier versions of Swift this code works perfectly.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) { timer in
    self.setOriginalState()
    self.shakeAnimation()
}
```

But in Swift 4 the following error appears:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'asyncAfter(deadline:qos:flags:execute:)'

How can one create a delay before running a sequence of code in Swift 4?

Comment: just remove "timer in".then work fine.

Comment: "In earlier versions of Swift this code works perfectly" Nevertheless, it was always wrong. All that happened is that the compiler stopped being so forgiving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying in playground it doesn't give any issue, that is just "missing" is the "timer" reference.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
    print("Dispatching after")
}

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3, qos: .userInteractive, flags: []) {
    print("Dispatching after")
}
```

They both seems to work, are you sure that the problem isn't somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn’t seem to be able to infer the type of parameters in the `asyncAfter` call. So you might want to specify the type like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + delay)
```

If you still get the same error make sure `delay` is of type `DispatchTimeInterval`. Here’s another example:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.milliseconds(300)
```

This should eventually silence the compiler.